# Multiple curl leads to "Too many open files error" on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl

I have an external REST API which handles storing data in "Data Store".

On a file upload, their is a Ruby library which calls this API and passes it the data array which then gets stored in the database by the external API.

I try to pass small chunks of array to the API so as to limit the post body content length in any curl call.

The library call looks like this

```
def add_data(table_name, table_data)

  url    =  "#{ExternalAPI::URL}/addData"
  m_curl = Curl::Multi.new

  begin

    chunks = table_data.each_slice(ExternalAPI::BATCH_SIZE).to_a

    chunks.each do |data_chunk|

      data = {
          "tableName" => table_name,
          "data"      => data_chunk
      }.to_json

      curl = Curl::Easy.new(url)
      curl.headers = {}
      curl.headers['Content-type'] = 'text/plain'
      curl.timeout = 300
      curl.post_body = data
      m_curl.add(curl)
    end

    m_curl.perform
    true

  rescue Exception => e
    puts "Curl Failed #{e.message}"
    puts "#{e.backtrace}"
    Rails.logger.error "Curl Failed #{e.message}"
    return false
  end

end
```

This causes too many open connections error in Webrick in development mode.
I assumed `Multi::Curl` either recycles the connections but I'm not sure whether that happens internally.

I also tried to create a new curl connection in the `for` loop and close it at the end of the loop (I know its inefficient) but it still led to the same error.

Can anyone please shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

I think `Multi::Curl` is going to try to execute all of your connections simultaneously.  You probably need to batch them into smaller groups.